# Reload the bootstrap datatable after every minute?

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using bootstrap server side datatable in my angularjs application and now i want to reload the data of that datatable after every minute.
So how can i do it?
I am using the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<table bs-table-control="matterTableControl"  id="matterTableControl"></table>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getMatterTable = (function () {
    $scope.matterTableControl = {
        options : {
            toolbar : "#get",
            url : url,
            dataField : 'rows',
            cache : false,
            sidePagination : 'server',
            pagination : false,
            showExport : false,
            queryParams : queryParams,
            clickToSelect : true,
            onClickRow : onClickRow,
            maintainSelected : true,
            columns : [{
                    field : 'ClientName',
                    title : 'Client',
                    align : 'left',
                    valign : 'bottom',
                    sortable : false
                }, {
                    field : 'Name',
                    title : 'Matter',
                    align : 'left',
                    valign : 'bottom',
                    sortable : false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to reload this by using following code  but getting no success:

```
$interval(function () {
   $scope.getMatterTable();
}.bind(this), 60000);
```

Documentation of Datatable:
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Example:
http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#integrate/angular

Github Code of datatable:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/tree/master/integrate/angular

Comment: `angular.element( document.querySelector( '#matterTableControl' ) ).bootstrapTable('refresh');` try this

Comment: Ohhh thanks man  @Vanjox.... Please send it in answer so i will mark it and upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap datatables ve a proper method to refresh the table:

```
angular.element( document.querySelector( '#matterTableControl' ) ).bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

it basically do this:

```
BootstrapTable.prototype.refresh = function (params) {
    if (params && params.url) {
        this.options.url = params.url;
        this.options.pageNumber = 1;
    }
    this.initServer(params && params.silent, params && params.query);
};
```

[Example](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/methods/refresh.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to refresh data-url of bootstrap table is to use refresh method and

```
$table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {url: 'new url'});
$table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'new url'});
```

If you don't doo refreshOptions then BootstrapTable still will use Old url for next refreshes. For example for pagination/sorting/search when server-side enabled.

Also if you have created table without JS then you could update URL in this way

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {url: 'new url'});
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'new url'});
```

If you need to add loader icon, then you should add before calling refresh method, and delete loader icon with onLoadSuccess, onLoadError events.

The documentation: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods